# Angular, stop rendering until get async data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have question regarding AngularJS. I want to make ng-repeat for some array. But data for this array i get from firebase in controller. 
Problem is, when page is rendering, iam still waiting for data from async function which get data from firebase.

What is the best way to control it? 
I tried to used promisses, but something was wrong and page was rendered before i got data from firebase.

i.e

```
$scope.games = [];
    function getOnce(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        ref.once("value", function(data) {
            defer.resolve();
            $scope.games.push('test');
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }

    $scope.getdata = getOnce().then(function(data){
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);

    });
```

And i call '$scope.getdata' function on init 'data-ng-init="getdata()"'
What i wrong here? Or how can i get my goal?

Comment: this is how async/promises are *supposed* to work.  The whole point of async is that other things can happen (like page rendering) while a server request is in progress.  the code you posted here doesn't really show what your problem really is, though, because it doesn't seem to be using whatever data it is trying to get.

Comment: shouldn't be using `ng-init` just to trigger controller function, call it in controller. Also `resolve` isn't passing any data down the promise chain

Comment: Your `getdata` property is not a function, its a promise object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass data in method resolve. In then populate the array with data response.

```
$scope.games = [];
    function getOnce(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        ref.once("value", function(data) {
        defer.resolve('test');
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

$scope.getdata = getOnce().then(function(data){
    $scope.games.push(data);
    console.log('success');
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use an `ng-show` to just hide the parts of the page you don't want visible while you're loading the data.  Or `ng-if` if your directives require that the data be loaded when their `link`/`controller` `function`s are ran by angular.

Does that suit your needs?

---

You'd need to expose whether or not you're done loading to the `$scope` with something like this:

```
$scope.isDoneLoading = false;
$scope.getdata = getOnce().then(function(data){
    // ...
    $scope.isDoneLoading = true;
});
```

Then you would just do this:

```
ng-if="isDoneLoading"
```

Or this, depending on your needs:

```
ng-show="isDoneLoading"
```